# Java Spring Boot don't connect with Google Cloud Logging, requires project ID

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I try use Google Cloud Logging in my Spring Boot Java Project.

I Include in the pom this dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>${google.protobuf.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-logging-logback</artifactId>
        <version>${google.cloud.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
      </dependency>
```

When my project run, it obtain this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@12:16 - RuntimeException in Action for tag [appender] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A project ID is required for this service but could not be determined from the builder or the environment.  Please set a project ID using the builder.
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:169)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reinitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:222)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:73)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:313)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:288)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:246)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:212)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at
```

I need to know how configure the Google credentials using the application.properties file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Configure Spring Cloud GCP Starter on your pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

...

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Then you can set your credentials on **application.properties** using:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.project-id=[YOUR_GCP_PROJECT_ID]
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:[LOCAL_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE]
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.scopes=[SCOPE_1],[SCOPE_2],[SCOPE_3]
```

---

Reference:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution that worked for me:

First, make sure that the environment variable GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT is setup, if it hasn't being setup.

For Spring Boot, you can do this by adding the line below, before `runApplication` is called:

```kotlin
 System.setProperty("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT", "your-project-id-goes-here")
```

Then, in the file `logback-spring.xml` you should add into your spring profile the following line:

```xml
<property name="projectId" value="${projectId:-${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}}"/>
```

Example

```xml
<configuration>
    <springProfile name="cloud">
        <property name="projectId" value="${projectId:-${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}}"/>
        <appender name="cloud" class="com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender">
            <redirectToStdout>true</redirectToStdout>
        </appender>
        <root level="debug">
            <appender-ref ref="cloud"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>
    <springProfile name="!cloud">
        <!--- more configuration for non cloud profiles --->
    </springProfile>
</configuration>
```

In this case, we use different profiles depending where our micro-service will run. So, I'm only showing the cloud profile